# Locking Face Area in Edit Mode

Tags: mesh, uv

I've get a mesh with a uv image texture on it. I'd like to animate peeling the surface off.

I'm trying to do with by duplicating a square region of mesh, and animate it peeling back using shape keys.

I'm having trouble modifying the mesh without stretching the mesh. Is there a good strategy to get my mesh peeled away without distorting its UV map?