# Is there a function to fix edge length in Blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms, edges

I hope this question is clear enough. I am trying to create a 3D model of a tesselated origami model. What I want to do is translate a vertex and have the surrounding vertices translate such that edges connecting them to the translated vertex keep their original length.

Here is an image of the origami model:

[image: Origami Model]

Here is an image of the 3D model of the flat tesselated pattern:

[image: 3D Model]

I hope you can see here that I would like to translate the centre points of the concave hexagons (the vertices currently selected) and have the connected edges keep their length as if it was made of a rigid material.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think is is the same as this question (http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18601/822) except for edges instead of faces.

Comment: Currerntly, I don't think there is any easy-and-accurate way to do so. For the specific case, manual adjustment can be acceptable, and almost unnoticable.

Comment: Don't have too much time to experiment on it, but have you tried with bones, inverse kinematics and such ?

Answer (score 4):

For the specific case, You may consider using cloth simulation to preserve the edge length:

**Step 1 to 3**: Create Unit; mirror + arrays; Apply modifiers + coloring for convenience. (For existing model, you can ignore above)

**Step 4**: Select all poked vertices, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to add to a new vertex group, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>) to add a hook.

**Step 5**: Add Cloth simulator. use the vertex group as pins.

**Step 6**: Scale the hook while simulating (playing animation). Then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> - <kbd>2</kbd> to convert the result. Finally, delete all unwanted faces.

[image]

[image]

**[Example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ojv5B6Lb-3UWVBcFlEWU5pWUU/view?usp=sharing)**

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Trying to get my head around this now.

Comment: OK. I understand the principle here. I'll continue to see if I can get the result I want and post back here.